# Handling Laravel project on a local machine and an Nginx server

Tags: laravel, nginx, laravel-6, laravel-mix, php-7.3

I have a Laravel project in my local machine that is currently in development, due to reasons, the application is showcase to people using an Nginx server, the problem is this, in the local machine I host the project in a root directory (`localhost:8000/`), but in the Nginx I host it in a folder (e.g. `10.x.x.x/webapp/`), this breaks a lot of stuff and I need to constantly change back and fort the reference to the assets and scripts I have, example:

- Font awesome fail to load because is looking for the `js` & `css` directories and not the `webapp/js` & `webapp/css` directories
- In a vue component holding a picture the picture won't load because is looking for `/img/picture.jpg` instead of `/webapp/img/picture.jpg`

The only way I manage to solve this is, in the case of Font awesome, is to add the `mix.setResourceRoot('/webapp')` parameter on the `webpack.mix.js` file, and in the case of the assets to add `/webapp` at the beggining, but doing that breaks everything on localhost, since now everything is pointing to a folder that doesn't exist in my machine.

What is a possible solution to have both running without constant reference changes? And what other possible problems could emerge?

Comment: In your localhost, translate `webapp` to `/` at the web server level. Something like `location ^~ /webapp { rewrite ^/(.*)$ $1 last; }`. This will allow to maintain `/webapp` on code.

Comment: Where would I put this?